# Stripe iOS integration - how do I know if Stripe is actually receiving my test inputs?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

So I have been trying to integrate Stripe with my swift code and so far I have the following code for testing. I printed the credit card number because it is required to create a token on Stripe's end, and it correctly reflects the testing credit card number (e.g. 4242424242424242) used by Stripe (I also did input random numbers for cvc and exp date), however, the "validateCardReturningError" always skips the "createTokenWithCard" function to execute "print("Error")". In an attempt to debug, I also commented out "validateCardReturningError" to see if I get a token back, but instead I get nil as the value for token.

This behavior leads me to believe that the communication to Stripe isn't actually happening, therefore no token is being generated. If so, is there a way to test the communication? Alternatively, is there a way to check to see what value is being returned from "validateCardReturningError"?

```
if (userExpiration.isEmpty){ let expArr = userExpiration.componentsSeparatedByString("/") 
    if (expArr.count > 1) { 
        let expMonth: NSNumber = Int(expArr[0])! 
        let expYear: NSNumber = Int(expArr[1])! 
        creditCard.expMonth = expMonth.unsignedLongValue 
        creditCard.expYear = expYear.unsignedLongValue } }

print(creditCard.number)

do {
    try creditCard.validateCardReturningError()
    STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard(
        creditCard,
        completion: { (token: STPToken?, stripeError: NSError?) -> Void in
            print(token) 
        })
} catch {        
        print("Error")
}
```

The errors I get when I printed stripeError is: 
`Optional(Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=50 "Missing required param:     exp_month." UserInfo={com.stripe.lib:ErrorMessageKey=Missing required param: exp_month., com.stripe.lib:ErrorParameterKey=card[expMonth], NSLocalizedDescription=Missing required param: exp_month.})`

Comment: What do you get in `stripeError`?

Comment: The following is what I get: 

Optional(Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=50 "Missing required param: exp_month." UserInfo={com.stripe.lib:ErrorMessageKey=Missing required param: exp_month., com.stripe.lib:ErrorParameterKey=card[expMonth], NSLocalizedDescription=Missing required param: exp_month.})

Comment: The relevant code for the month is: 

 if (userExpiration.isEmpty){
            let expArr = userExpiration.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
            if (expArr.count > 1)
            {
                let expMonth: NSNumber = Int(expArr[0])!
                let expYear: NSNumber = Int(expArr[1])!
                
                creditCard.expMonth = expMonth.unsignedLongValue
                creditCard.expYear = expYear.unsignedLongValue
            }
        }

Comment: You should edit the question and add the errors and additional code there, it will be way more readable.

Comment: Note that in your code, you're doing something with the expiration only if the expiration is empty (`if (userExpiration.isEmpty)`), rather than when it isn't. So when the user actually entered any data, you're not using it and not sending it. Add a `!` to negate the test.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (userExpiration.isEmpty)
```

to

```
if (!userExpiration.isEmpty)
```

so that you actually use the expiration date when there's something in there.

Also add an `else` clause to complain if it's empty, and prevent submission (I suppose this code is run when the user submits the form).

Comment: Oh thanks for the catch. I got the token ID now. Finally!

Answer (score 0):

Stripe actually lets you browse all of the logs for your account in your dashboard. So if you head to https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs?method=not_get, you'll be able to see if you're successfully POSTing to the `/v1/tokens` endpoint.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about this. But I see nothing in the log. It does seem like communication is interrupted because of the missing "exp_month" but I think my code above covers it?

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying now. I had my Stripe dashboard set to "Live" and that's why I'm not seeing anything in my log. Now I've set it to "Test" and I see the errors. Thanks.